# Writing Custom functions to grab data from JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where i am using VueJS as front-end framework.

I've so much data in JSON format to work with for that i've written a helper function to retrieve data from JSON. much like we query SQL for table rows.

here is what i wrote

```
function getWhere(field, value) { 
   var result = [];

    $vm.services.forEach(function(object, key){
       if(object[field] == value) { 
            result.push(object) 
        }
    })   

   return result.length == 1 ? result[0] : result;
 }
```

**2 Questions**

- Is it okay to grab data from JS objects like this i mean iterating the whole object to get a single field?
- Is there a built-in solution in JS or VueJS for this kind of tasks, if Yes should i use those solutions or the function i posted here is okay to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result[0] : result
```

This is a bad idea. This will keep users of your functions guessing and unnecessarily put in guard logic to check if it's a thing, or an array of things before proceeding. If you expect many results, then always return an array. If you expect just one result, return just one (regardless of how many match), and `null` if none.

> iterating the whole object to get a single field

Array searches are [`O(n)` at worst](http://bigocheatsheet.com/). Tough luck if you're item is on the tip of the list. While we can't do anything in the complexity side of things, your code could be simplified. Seeing `$vm.services` appears to be an array, you can just use [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
// Will always return an array, regardless of match count
function getWhere(field, value) { 
  return $vm.services.filter(function(object){
    return object[field] === value;
  });
});
```

Alternatively, if you just really want one item among all matches, then [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is your guy. It takes the same form as `filter`, but stops going through the array when it hits a match and just returns that one item, without wrapping it in an array.

```
// Will always return 1 item from the array, and undefined if none
function getWhere(field, value) { 
  return $vm.services.find(function(object){
    return object[field] === value;
  });
});
```

> Is there a built-in solution in JS or VueJS for this kind of tasks, if Yes should i use those solutions or the function i posted here is okay to use.

Yes, `filter` and `find` are just a few of many. See [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2).